# Getting error while setting alpha of UIView Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm making quiz app and when I want to change value of alpha of my UIView I'm getting error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, before it warms fine but I'm remodeling my app and I think that I delete something or change by mistake. I don't want to put all my code here because it is quiet large so I will cut most important parts.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answerStackView: UIStackView!

// Feedback screen
@IBOutlet weak var resultView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var dimView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var feedbackLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resultButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var resultViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var resultViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var currentQuestion:Question?

var  model:QuizModel?
var questions = [Question]()

var numberCorrect = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    model = QuizModel()
    model?.getQuestions()
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
func setAll(questionsReturned:[Question]) {

    self.loadViewIfNeeded()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Hide feedback screen
    dimView.alpha = 0

    // Call get questions
    questions = questionsReturned

    // Check if there are questions
    if questions.count > 0 {

        currentQuestion = questions[0]

        // Load state
        loadState()

        // Display the current question
        displayCurrentQuestion()
    }

print("Called!")

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayCurrentQuestion() {

    if let actualCurrentQuestion = currentQuestion {

        // Set question label to alpha 0
        questionLabel.alpha = 0

        // Set the question label
        questionLabel.text = actualCurrentQuestion.questionText

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { 

                self.questionLabel.alpha = 1

            }, completion: nil)

        // Create the answer buttons and place them into the scrollview
        createAnswerButtons()

        // Save state
        saveState()
    }

}
```

im getting error while setting alpha of `dimView` and `questionLabel`. I don't know why because they are connected by the storyboard

PS. When I set breakpoint on this `dimView.alpha = 0` and type `po dimview` in console it says that `dimView` is `nil`

Edit: I have some informations that can be useful. When I set alpha of `DimView` and `questionLabel` before I call `model?.getQuestions()` it works and when I set breakpoint there and type `po dimView!` into console it returns some values. [image]

And `questionsLabel` have something too. [image]

But when code goes into `model?.getQuestions()`, and then I type `po dimView!` it returns nil.  [image]

Comment: I know what is optional and nil but I don't know why is it nil, it shouldn't be

Comment: Because you didn't connect your outlet(s). Please read the answer to the question I linked. It covers how to find and fix such issues.

Comment: I wrote replay for an answer that was deleted that I checked outlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setAll(questionsReturned:[Question])` is getting called before `viewDidLoad()` is called. The @IBOutlets aren't connected until just before `viewDidLoad()` is called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    var myText: String = ""

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myLabel.text = myText
    }

    set(myText: String) {
        self.myText = myText
    }
}
```

Do it like the above...

-- Edit --

I notice in your screenshots that `displayCurrentQuestion` is being called on a different view controller object than the view controller that was loaded in the screenshot where `viewDidLoad` is called. It could be that you are creating a second view controller somewhere?

Do this... Put break points at the beginning of your `displayCurrentQuestion` and `viewDidLoad` methods. Then run your app. You will find that either `displayCurrentQuestion` is getting called *before* `viewDidLoad` is, or it is being called on a different object that `viewDidLoad` was called on (you can tell it's a different object by the hex value of the `self` variable.)

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of trying to change the state of IBOutlets inside `setAll`, create some properties with the information (this is called a Model) and then set the IBOutlets in `viewDidLoad` from the model.

Comment: Im trying to understand what I have to do, you mean that I have to create another file/function where I will set this values? Sorry, I'm new to swift and programming

Comment: I added code to my answer

Comment: is it only one way to do that? I have a lot staff like that

Comment: oh I think I got it, I have to do that only with properties in 'setAll()' function ?

Comment: Every view controller should have a property that represents it's model. Some outside source sets the view controller's model, and then in the viewDidLoad, the view controller sets up the views based on the state of the model. The only other option is to not call your `setAll` method until after viewDidLoad starts.

Comment: But you mean `func set(myText: String) {
        self.myText = myText
    } ` ?

Comment: I have edited my post and added some informations from debugging that can be useful

Comment: I edited my answer. The answer is essentially the same but it might be that you have two view controllers in existence...

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to check your IBOutlet connections with your viewcontroller in storyboard, there might be wrong connections

Comment: I check that  3 times :)

Comment: As I see you get the questions with **model?.getQuestions()** **onViewDidLoad** and handle it with **setAll** so the IBOutlets connections should be fine if nothing wrong

Comment: I have edited my post and added some informations from debugging that can be useful